# ユーザーの情報の更新について

Tags: php, laravel

ユーザー情報の更新(Edit~Update)をやっています。

#### 実現したいこと

パスワードだけ更新したい時、メールアドレスだけ更新したい時、どちらかを入力をして更新させたい。

#### 現状

パスワードだけ入力して更新すると、"メールアドレスはすでに存在しています。" というエラーになってしまいます。
パスワードを変更するために、メールアドレスも変更しないといけない、仕組みになってしまっている。

rulesメソッドを以下のように編集しました。uniqueになっているにで、バリデーションに引っかかってしまいます。
とはいえ、UserRequestを削除してしまうと、どんな値でも保存されてしまうので困っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user     = User::find($id);
    $name     = $request->input('name');
    $email    = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $params   = [
      'name'      => $name,
      'email'     => $email,
      'password'  => Hash::make($password),
    ];
    $this->authorize('update', $user);
    if (!$user->userSave($params)) {
      // 更新失敗
      return redirect()
             ->route('user.edit', ['user' => $user->id])
             ->with('error_message', 'Update user failed');
    }
    return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('flash_message', 'update success!!');
}
```

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6',
        'password_confirmation' => 'filled',
    ];

   if ($this->password_confirmation) {
    $rules['name']      = 'required|max:20';
    $rules['email']     = 'required|email|unique:users';
    $rules['password']  = 'required|min:6|confirmed';
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのためにuniqueでは「このIDだけは除外する」指定ができる。

```php
$rules['email']     = 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user()->id;
```

簡単に書くためのRuleクラスもある。

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$rules['email'] = ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user()->id)];
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。思っていた通りの挙動になりました。